cssnano@7.0.3: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module
error cssnano@7.0.3: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "^18.12.0 || ^20.9.0 || >=22.0". Got "16.18.0"
error Found incompatible module.


I used node versions 16.18.0, 18.12.0, 20.9.0, 22.0.0 but it is not working.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

What is the output when you use node version 22.0.0?

I faced this error when updating dependencies in a Nuxt 2 project running on Node v16. There is an issue pointing a mismatch between the required Node versions for @nuxt/webpack and cssnano, but since no solution was provided, I ended up pinning cssnano version using overrides in my package.json file:
"overrides": {
    "cssnano": "5.1.15"   
}

